# European alternatives to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, virtual-drive

[Dropbox](http://getdropbox.com) is positively brilliant, but the data center is probably in the US somewhere. Since I'm in Europe, there's plenty of lag and a poor upload rate.

Are there any similar services using data centers in Europe? 
I'm looking for a free plan (cirka 2GB), so sites like Amazon S3 aren't good answers.

Comment: I doubt that using a European alternative would increase speeds of transfer that much, i mean i use dropbox and cant complain about the speed

Comment: I also am quite content with the speed. also, the service is not really designed for big changes, I think. If you want free, there's probably no better way too keep up to 2GB of files in sync over a multitude of machines.

Comment: Though Dropbox is not purely backup, see also "Best choice for a personal “online backup” in Europe" at http://superuser.com/questions/19775/best-choice-for-a-personal-online-backup-in-europe/

Comment: Likewise, I am based in the UK and have no speed problems with Dropbox and reasonably sized files.

Comment: Also, if you are a European business, you have to comply with personal data protection guidelines, which means not uploading any personal data (customer names, addresses) to a "foreign" server without the person's permission.  So that Excel list should not live in Dropbox. :-(

Comment: You can go with Nextcloud (open-source and made in Germany) on-premise or one of the providers, some have a free plan https://nextcloud.com/providers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any real answer to what I'm looking for. Humyo came close except for the web-only interface. Free... you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 3):

Using Linux you could make an alternative yourself - see the following for further details:

> http://fak3r.com/2009/09/14/howto-build-your-own-open-source-dropbox-clone/

Comment: I didn't explicitly mention that I was not interested in building a service myself - but that's the case. I'm looking for existing online services. Also, if the Linux server is under my desk and burglars grab both that and my desktop, then I've gained nothing.

Answer (score 2):

[Humyo](http://www.humyo.com/pages/en/online-file-storage) is a German company with datacenters in the UK. They offer a 10 GB free plan.

Comment: Their website now only offers "first 2 months free" but not a normal "free" plan.

Comment: This link leads me to an account creation page that says they still have a free account: https://www.humyo.com/pages/en/free-online-file-storage

Comment: What you were seeing was for the paid account which gave you 2 months for free; but there's an option for a free account. From the website: "No frills, no support, 10GB online storage, free **forever**"

Comment: Thanks for the direct link! I didn't see that on the homepage. Good: it's really free and not just a trial. Bad: it's web-only, no integration in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/) by Lacie. They have a 2GB free plan. According to their website, their servers are in Switzerland, Germany, and France.

Comment: Wuala also encrypts file BEFORE sending them to their servers. This adds to security!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) from Microsoft. It's free for 4 GB. I have no problems with the speed (I'm also based in Europe).

Comment: im too in Europe, and I only want to tell that there is 25 GB of available space, not 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows you could try [SDExplorer](http://www.cloudstorageexplorer.com/), which integrates with Windows Explorer. They give you 25GB of space.

Comment: Sorry, you're dissing MS so loudly that I missed your real point?

Answer (score 0):

[Nomadesk](http://www.nomadesk.com) is a Belgian company I work for. It offers solid back-up, filesharing and synchronization. More: all your files are protected with encryption and Theftguard.

The storage is unlimited, and we doesn't charge per user but per fileserver you use.

Don't hesitate to give it a try (30 day free trial) and let us know what you think of it!

Comment: +1 for mentioning you're associated with them, -1 for not answering the question: He wants a free plan.

Comment: Hi Daniel! 

You are correct, Nomadesk doesn't offer a free plan. But that's because we combine protection, synchronization, sharing and storage. Most freemium models only give a small part of that package. We rather want to give the full ànd unlimited package, but there's a small price on it ($50/year). If you are really looking for a free plan, in that case: indeed Nomadesk is excluded. It is a question of what's most important to you: price or features.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Dropbox uses Amazon S3](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=27889), which happen to have [data centers all over the world](http://aws.amazon.com/en/s3/faqs/#Where_is_my_data_stored), including Ireland.